# Why does the Windows Command Prompt COPY command write error messages to STDOUT not STDERR?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, stderr, copy

Normally if you try to copy a file that does not exist you get an error message:

```
C:\temp>copy foo bar
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I would expect that error message to be written to STDERR but it appears to be written to STDOUT:

```
C:\temp>copy foo bar >out

C:\temp>dir

 Directory of C:\temp

23/09/2019  16:18                44 out
               1 File(s)             44 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  885,229,346,816 bytes free

C:\temp>type out
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The same apparently happens if you redirect STDERR separately from STDOUT

```
C:\temp>del out

C:\temp>copy foo bar 2>err >out

C:\temp>dir

 Directory of C:\temp

23/09/2019  16:10                 0 err
23/09/2019  16:10                44 out
               2 File(s)             44 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  885,226,635,264 bytes free

C:\temp>type out
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I am using Windows 10

```
C:\temp>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.356]
```

Why does COPY not write error messages to STDERR? Where is this behaviour documented?

Comment: This is not execution error. This is parameter error not relative to the copying process, which have not started yet.

Comment: @Akina: It's still an error and as such should go to stderr. In fact, it is exactly the kind of error that [stderr was _invented for_.](https://web.archive.org/web/20180929232212/https://minnie.tuhs.org//pipermail/tuhs/2013-December/004497.html)

Comment: @grawity Program author is the only who can decide what problem is error and what is not. But in this particular case `%ERRORLEVEL% = 1` - so it is really programmer's mistake.